# Question on the second homomorphism theorem.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, group-isomorphism

I'm not much familiar with this topic, but nontheless I have a problem understanding the context. Following this link [Second Isomorphism Theorem](https://math.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Abstract_and_Geometric_Algebra/First-Semester_Abstract_Algebra%3A_A_Structural_Approach_(Sklar)/09%3A_The_Isomorphism_Theorem/9.02%3A_The_Second_and_Third_Isomorphism_Theorems), they state that $HN/N$ is a group under left coset multiplication. They then define the map $\phi(h)=hN$ (a map from $H$ to $HN/N$) where $N$ is a normal subgroup of a larger group $G$ and $H$ is a subgroup of $G$. Furthermore they state $\phi$ is clearly a homomorphism. How is that? How do I understand the algebraic operation between these elements?

For instance, we would have to have $\phi(h\cdot h^{-1})=\phi(e)=N=\phi(h)\cdot \phi(h)^{-1}=hN\cdot (hN)^{-1}$. So as far as I undertand, the elements of $HN/N$ are the cosets of $HN$, right? How do you take the inverse of a coset?

Comment: Yes, I see that, but why is $NN=N$? What is $NN$ even supposed to mean?

Comment: Sorry, I just deleted my comment to write an answer :-) $NN=\{nm\mid n, m\in N\}$ and by taking $n=1$ we see that $N\leq NN$, while clearly $NN\leq N$ as $N$ is closed under multiplication.

Comment: Isnt' $\varphi$ the restriction to H of the projection on the quotient?

Comment: @Diger $NN=\{nm | n\in N, m\in N\}$

Comment: Is it just a definition, or does it follow from a specific operation?

Comment: @Diger what are you referring to?

Comment: @Diger If that is about my (now deleted-sorry!) comment, it is how the group operation on the cosets $G/N$ is *defined*.

Comment: Ok, I see. Thanks @SineoftheTime: Yes, I was wondering if the group operation is to be defined this way or if $NN=N$ follows from a specific operation (which I may not have been aware of, that there is an operation between sets).

Comment: $NN$ is a notation for $\{nm | n\in N, m\in N\}$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the thing you are struggling with is the definition of the group operation on $HN/N$, or more generally on $G/N$. Here, multiplication is defined as:
$$gNhN=ghN$$
which makes sense, as by normality of $N$ we have $gNhN=g(hNh^{-1})hN=ghNN=ghN$.
Therefore, inverses are as follows:
$$(gN)^{-1}=g^{-1}N$$

As the map you are considering is defined by $\phi(h)=hN$, we clearly have:
$$\phi(g)\phi(h)=gNhN=ghN=\phi(gh)$$
as required for homomorphisms.

Comment: So, just for completeness: I could think of $NN^{-1}=\{nm^{-1}|n,m\in N\}=\{nm|n,m\in N\}=N$, since $N$ is a group $m^{-1}\in N$ and when $m$ runs over all elements of $N$, so does $m^{-1}$.

Comment: Yeah - $NN=N=N^{-1}N=NN^{-1}$ etc.

Answer (score 2):

The "elements" in the quotient group are those cosets of $N$, and $N$ works as the unit element. Suppose you take some element $hN$, the inverse is also some coset, say $bN$, which satisfies

$$hNbN=N$$

Since $N$ is normal, namely $Nb=bN$, hence we have

$$hNbN=hbNN=hbN=N$$

This implies

$$hb\in N\Longrightarrow b\in h^{-1}N\Longrightarrow b=h^{-1}n_1,~~n_1\in N$$

so we get the inverse

$$(hN)^{-1}=bN=h^{-1}n_1N=h^{-1}N$$

Answer (score 1):

Consider a group $G$, $H$ subgroup of $G$ and $N$ a normal subgroup of $G$. The projection $p:G\to G/N$ defined letting $p(g)=gN$ for all $g\in G$ is well defined and it's a surjective group homomorphism.
It's easy to prove that $p(H)=HN/N$, hence $\phi=(p_{|H})^{|HN/N}$ is a group homomorphism.